# Is there any Material Node Setup load time info available - as in animation nodes?

Tags: node-editor, animation-nodes

I'm wondering if there's a way how to toggle on node setup load time info as they have in animation nodes add-on. It would help me to measure the performance optimizations of my procedural shaders.

Here is what I mean:

[image]

Also, is there any way of getting a viewer node, that would write the imported values as text, again, as they have in animation nodes add-on? This one:

https://docs.animation-nodes.com/documentation/nodes/viewer/viewer/

Thanks a lot!